# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get') on using livewire-charts

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I am trying to use this package `https://github.com/asantibanez/livewire-charts` but get this error when trying to see my chart, I just copy and paste it from docs:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')
at Proxy.drawChart (app.js:3:472873)
at app.js:3:472785
```

To Reproduce
Steps to reproduce the behavior:

```
$columnChartModel =
(new ColumnChartModel())
->setTitle('Expenses by Type')
->addColumn('Food', 100, '#f6ad55')
->addColumn('Shopping', 200, '#fc8181')
->addColumn('Travel', 300, '#90cdf4')
;


<livewire:livewire-column-chart
:column-chart-model="$columnChartModel"
/>


Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')
at Proxy.drawChart (app.js:3:472873)
at app.js:3:472785
```

[image]
Is here anybody who have experience with it?

Answer (score 0):

**check the requirement must be like that**
[requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYP6J.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Ahmed I do that but still didn't work